# A bit of chicken?

Tags: terminology

I heard someone earlier today say this.

'I will cut the chicken breast into bits then fry.'

I responded;

'You mean chunks?, because I would prefer strips.'

That someone then said;

'Strips? Thats what I meant by bits.'

When someone says a bit of chicken breast, am I suppose to think chunk or strip?

Comment: *Bits* normally means something much smaller than "strips".   And "strips" aren't "chunks".  Strips are thin and long cuts and chunks are irregular in shape and roughly as wide as they are long.  Plural "bits" is different from singular "a bit of".

Comment: The more important question, was it actually chicken and not possum?

Comment: I live in the UK it's most likely to be Rat. haha.

Comment: @TimRomano - So long as it tastes like chicken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When someone says a bit of chicken breast, am I suppose to think chunk
>   or strip?

A *[bit](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bit)* is a generic reference to **size**, and has no reference to **shape**:

> noun
>
> 1 A small piece, part, or quantity of something:

The following [synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/bit?s=t) for *bit* have a bit more **shape** connotation:

> - Chip
> - Chunk
> - Crumb
> - Dollop
> - Droplet
> - Flake
> - Lump
> - Shred
> - Slice
> - Sliver
> - Strip
>
> *thesaurus.com*

Even the notion of small can be subjectively ambiguous, and other [synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/bit?s=t) for bit reflect its **generic** nature:

> - atom
> - dab
> - dash
> - grain
> - portion
> - taste
> - trace
>
> *thesaurus.com*

Communication is a process of *estimated meaning*, and sometimes the first try can fall short, so we use synonyms to refine the estimate until everyone agrees.